# Sum of two submodules of a module, each of which is a direct summand, is again a direct summand?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, direct-sum

Let $N,P$ be submodules of a module $M$ such that $N,P$ are direct summands of $M$.

> Is it true that $N+P$ is also a direct summand of $M$ ?

Comment: While looking for an answer, I progressed a little bit, but still, I am not totally sure the statement is true or not. Let $N,P$ be submodules of $M$ such that both $N$ and $P$ are direct summands of $M$, i.e. that there exists $N'$ and $P'$ two submodules of $M$ such that $M$ is the internal direct sum of $N$, $N'$ or of $P$, $P'$. It is possible to show that 
$$ M\simeq N\oplus N'\qquad \&\qquad M\simeq P\oplus P'.$$
Then, my best guess while looking at exemples with the Chinese remainder theorem is something along the lines of
$$ (N+P)+(N'\cap P')$$
as a factorisation of $M$.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is **no**, here is a counterexample: Consider the $\mathbb Z$-module $M = \mathbb Z^2$ with the two submodules $N = \mathbb Z\cdot (1,0)$, $P = \mathbb Z \cdot (1,2)$. Both are direct summands since the generating elements can each be completed to a basis with $(0,1)$. We have $M/(N+P) \cong \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$, so the quotient map doesn't split and therefore $N+P$ is not a direct summand.